# OAuth, OpenID and native login - is it worth joining identities?

Tags: authentication, openid, oauth

When using OAuth, OpenID for login (together with native login on the site) there is the possibility of the same user having multiple accounts on a site. It is probably that the user who has Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo!, Google etc etc will forget which ID they used to login the site. I'm thinking of giving them the option of 'joining' their various accounts into one. This way their posts are in one place for them to manage.

Is there something flawed with this thinking?

Answer (score 1):

The only flaw is assuming that one identity must equal one account.

As you can see here on stackoverflow, users can have two openid identities pointing to one account. Nothing stops you from allowing more identities per account on your site, and that's a good idea -- not because people will not have to remember what identity did they use, but because they will have a backup in case of one of the providers disappearing.

Of course, you could also create an option of joining existing accounts, but that's way more complicated, and I don't think it would be popular (because people rarely create two accounts just to have them associated).

Comment: "people rarely create two accounts just to have them associated" ... true, but some people might create two accounts accidentally because when they come to login they are given an array of choices and do not realise that they need to use the same identity as last time. (Cookies will help but might not be available or the user is on a different computer, etc.) Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this use case is quite difficult for lay people to understand and will require a lot of work to streamline the user experience.  Whether it is worth it will depend on the nature of your application, your typical use cases, and user expectations.

There are actually two aspects:

- Adding another login vector to an existing account (I've logged in via Facebook, now I want to login with Twitter to the same account)
- Merging two or more independent accounts that were created separately, i.e. by accident, and each have user-generated content of their own

Merging two accounts is harder, because you have to pick a winner and re-associate all the other's content with the preferred account.  Depending on your use cases, this may actually cause some content to be removed (like if the two accounts both upvoted the same Stack Overflow question).

For multiple vectors, you must be sure that the user will understand what it means to login to the same account either with one method or the other.  (And for some application, that may not actually make much sense as a concept.)  And for a merge, you have to ensure that users understand that a merge is non-reversible, and ensure that merges cannot be easily done by accident (i.e. by two different users on a shared computer).

Is it worth it?  Just my opinion, but I think if your application encourages users to maintain a sense of ownership of "their" content, AND associates user identity and content together, it is probably worth it in the long run.